# <hr> with display block is adding scroll bars if I dynamically change the margin

Tags: javascript

I have created a hr tag with below style

```
  hr{   
     /* margin:5%; */
     height:10px;
     display:block;
  }​
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/thKb8/4/) is the fiddle
It is displayed properly. Occupying 100% width of the screen. But if I change the margin Dynamically through JavaScript Console. It is overflowing from screen. How can I make this auto adjustable based on margins.

Comment: what code you used through console?

Comment: document.getElementById('ele').style.margin = "5%". Like this I am giving in a normal html page debugging console

Comment: Can't reproduce. What browser?

Comment: Same as @Nenotlep said, in Google Chrome.
The `hr` has it's margins applied as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
document.getElementById('a').style.margin= "5%";
```

Try this:

```
document.getElementById('a').style.margin= "5px";
```